# How to read quotation marks in a CSV File?

Tags: c++, file, printing

As the title suggests, my program needs to read a file that has quotation marks and separated by a comma. I am new to C++ and I am not sure how to do that. The file it trying to read is a CSV type of a file. Any assistance would be very helpful! The format in the file is this: “Mary”, “000111222”, “Junior”, 12, 4.0
The expected output should be the same. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

class Student {

//declare local variables
protected:
 string name;   
 string ssn;     // Social Secturity Number. 
 string gpa;        //Most up to date gpa for the student
 string credits;    //Number of student's credit hours

                //build public methods
 public:

 // Default Constructor
 Student() {}



Student(const string n, const string s, string sGPA, string sCredits) {

    name = n;
    ssn = s;
    gpa = sGPA;
    credits = sCredits;
}
string getName() {
    return name;
}
string getSSN() {
    return ssn;
}
string getGPA() {
    return gpa;
}
string getCredit() {
    return credits;
}
virtual void print() const {

    cout << '\n' << endl;
    cout << "Student's name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Student SSN: " << ssn << endl;
    cout << "Student's current GPA: " << gpa << endl;
    cout << "Student's credit hours: " << credits << endl;
}


virtual float tuition() const = 0;
 };

 class Undergrad : public Student {

 //declare local variables

 protected:
 float undergrad_rate = 380.0;
 string year;


//build public methods

 public:


Undergrad() {}


//Undergrad Constructor
Undergrad(const string n, const string s, string uGPA, string uCredits, string y) :
    Student(n, s, uGPA, uCredits), year(y) {}


//Display the contents of undergrad
void print() const {
    Student::print();
    cout << "Undergrad Rate: " << undergrad_rate << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << year << endl;
}


//Display undergrad's current year
string get_year() {
    return year;
}


//Display the undergrad's current rate
float get_rate() {
    return undergrad_rate;
}


//Set a undergrad's current year
void set_year(string y) {
    year = y;
}


//Display the cost for an undergrad to attend university
float tuition() const {
    return 1000000;
}
};

int main() {
ifstream ip("data.txt");

if (!ip.is_open()) std::cout << "ERROR: File not found" << '/n';
string name;
string ssn;
string year;
string credit;
string gpa;

vector<Undergrad> file;
//Undergrad g(name, ssn, year, credit, gpa);
while (ip.good()) {
    getline(ip, name, ',');
    getline(ip, ssn, ',');
    getline(ip, year, ',');
    getline(ip, credit, ',');
    getline(ip, gpa, '\n');

    Undergrad g(name, ssn, year, credit, gpa);
    file.push_back(g);
}

ip.close();
for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
    cout << "Name: " << file[i].getName() << endl;
    cout << "SSN: " << file[i].getSSN() << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << file[i].get_year() << endl;
    cout << "Credit:  " << file[i].getCredit() << endl;
    cout << "GPA " << file[i].getGPA() << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;


}

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please copy the strange symbols here?

Comment: You should debug your program.  The simplest thing you could start doing is to print out right after you read in a value, to verify it is good before you create an `Undergrad` add it to `file`.

Comment: @Yola 
Name: ôMaryö
SSN: ô000111222ö
Year: 4.0
Credit: 12.0
GPA: ôJuniorö

Comment: @HenryReichard So did you do as my comment suggested?  What is the actual value you're reading in?

Comment: I did, I figured the problem is the program is not reading the quotation marks properly. Im not sure how to fix that in the code.

Comment: So maybe it is your file that is at fault?  What is the actual quotation mark characters in your file?  Are they the traditional ASCII quotation marks?

Comment: This is the contends of the file: “Mary”, “000111222”, “Junior”, 12, 4.0
This is what the expected result should be: “Mary”, “000111222”, “Junior”, 12, 4.0. 
Instead it gives this result: ôMaryö  ô000111222ö  4.0 Credit: 12.0  ôJuniorö

Comment: No, do not try to type in what you see -- it will not prove anything.  Verify the file yourself -- what are the actual quotation mark characters used?  Don't be surprised if the quotation marks are *not* ASCII quotation marks.

Comment: How would I verify the file?

Comment: You can look at the file in a hex editor.  Or print the ASCII value of each of those characters in the string you're reading.  An ASCII double quote is hex 22 (decimal 34).  If it's something else, then those are not traditional ASCII quotes.  My crystal ball is saying that those characters look like double quotes, but are not double quotes.

Comment: yeah it showing a hexcode of 93 and 94. Im not sure how it got there

Comment: @HenryReichard If you look up ASCII hex 93 (147), it is the "o" with a circumflex accent.  So I guess the root of the problem has been found.

Comment: I just fixed the issue! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like some weird quoting with 'ô' as the open-quote character and 'ö' as close-quote character. Probably mangled by Windows charset or Unicode encoding.